# Losing decimal while dividing in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm having to create a random math generator in visual basic, when a user selects divide it should show the number to the second decimal. Anything I have tried so far keeps rounding off. 
option strict on is required

this is the code I have so far

```
Private Sub DivisionProblem()
    ' Divide two numbers and display the answer
    Dim numSmallestNum As Integer = CreateANumber()
    Dim numLargestNum As Integer = CreateANumber()
    Dim strToWork As String


    If (numLargestNum > numSmallestNum) Then
        strToWork = (Convert.ToString(numLargestNum) & " / " & Convert.ToString(numSmallestNum))
        lblToWork.Text = strToWork

        _decAnswer = CInt((Decimal.Round(CDec(numLargestNum / numSmallestNum), 2)))

    Else
        strToWork = (numSmallestNum & " / " & numLargestNum)
        lblToWork.Text = strToWork
        _decAnswer = CInt((Decimal.Round(CDec(numSmallestNum / numLargestNum), 2)))
    End If
End Sub
```

if anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it. thank you!

Comment: `_decAnswer` is not a legal VBA identifier. And `CInt` converts to `Integer`, which is, well, an *integer* data type. And `Option Strict` is a VB.NET thing - VBA and VB.NET are completely different things. Start by removing `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic` from your modules if you want to write idiomatic .net code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB CStr, CDate, CBool, etc. vs. DirectCast for casting without conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379537/vb-cstr-cdate-cbool-etc-vs-directcast-for-casting-without-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim numSmallestNum As Integer = CreateANumber()
Dim numLargestNum As Integer = CreateANumber()
```

Declare these two `As Decimal` and there's no need to convert anything.

Answer (score 3):

CInt forces the value to be of Integer not Double.

Comment: It's forcing me to use CInt, could there be another way to convert it?

Comment: What is forcing you?

Comment: Option strict on is, it's disallowing conversion from double to integer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to `Dim _decAnswer as Decimal` and use [`CDec`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cdec.php) instead of `CInt`.

For additional context on the `Decimal` type, [check out this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx)

You might also want to consider using `Double` and `CDbl` instead of `Decimal` and `CDec`, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know an `Integer` does not save decimals. Use `Dim ... As Decimal`. Just make life easier