# Option Strict and Unboxing Object to String

Tags: vb.net, string, treenode, unboxing

I have a treeview where some of the treenodes have a string saved into their tag object and some of the tags are left as nothing. Later on I want to use the strings for something, in the nodes where they exist.

```
For Each tn As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tn.Tag) Then
        Call DoTagStringStuff(tn.Tag)
    End If
Next tn
```

This worked fine until I needed to turn on option strict to make my code compatible with a co-workers project. I'm a bit confused about how to best unbox the string from the treenode.tag object.

The error popup suggest using `CStr`, but I was under the impression that the `CStr` function was only in VB.net as a throwback to VB6, and really shouldn't be used for new code. If I try `tn.Tag.toString` in the above code, I get an error at runtime when it fails to compute `Nothing.toString`.

What is the right way to fix this? Should I even be using the tag object to hold string values in the first place, or is there a better treenode property that wouldn't require unboxing I can use for this?

Edit: I think perhaps this would be correct?

```
For Each tn As TreeNode In theNode.Nodes
    If tn.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
        Call DoTagStringStuff(DirectCast(tn.Tag, String))
    End If
Next tn
```

Except I'm not checking for an empty or only whitespace string anymore.

Comment: No, CStr() is not a throwback. You can use the object's ToString() method instead if you prefer.  It is actually the Tag property that's a VB6 throwback.  You in general avoid its usage by separating the model from the view.

Comment: The `Tag` is present on most (if not all) controls. I don't see the problem of using this in certain cases. I don't know the case of the TS, but it isn't a throwback per se ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm a bit confused about how to best unbox the string from the treenode.tag object.

First off, there is no boxing or unboxing involved here.  Since `String` is a class, an `Object` variable can directly hold a reference to a `String` without boxing.  Boxing occurs when you store a value type (`Structure`) within an `Object` variable.

That being said - to extract the value, since you know you're always storing a `String`, you can use `DirectCast` to pull out the value:

```
For Each tn As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
    Dim tag = DirectCast(tn.Tag, String)
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag) Then
        Call DoTagStringStuff(tag)
    End If
Next tn
```

If other types could potentially be stored in the `Tag`, or if `Tag` may be left empty, then [other conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782/65358)  may be appropriate.

Comment: That's just the problem, sometimes the tag is left as `Nothing`, but that's the only exception. If there's anything in the tag at all, I know it's a `String`. I think what I might need is a method like `DirectCast( tn.Tag, String)` that's smart enough to turn a `tn.Tag` value of `Nothing` into a `String` value of `Nothing`.

Comment: @Odinsonnah You could just put the null check before the `DirectCast`, or use `CType` or `CStr` instead of `DirectCast`, in that case.

Comment: I tested the code, turns out that DirectCast does in fact work correctly here even when the tag is nothing, so this is a complete solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CStr` to cast/convert the tag to a string is totally legitimate:

```
DoTagStringStuff(CStr(tn.Tag))
```

If you don't care for the `CStr` syntax, you can use either `DirectCast` or `CType`, instead.  `CStr` is essentially just shorthand for `CType(x, String)`.  While `CStr` did exist in VB6, it is not considered out-dated to use it.  It is still considered to be a function of the core VB.NET language.

Technically, since you know that the property references a `String` object, the best choice would actually be `DirectCast`:

```
DoTagStringStuff(DirectCast(tn.Tag, String))
```

`DirectCast` is slightly more efficient when you don't intend any conversion of the value to take place.  As a side benefit, it's more self-documenting.  Anyone who reads that line will know that the `Tag` is a reference to a `String` object, whereas if you used `CStr` or `ToString`, that wouldn't be obvious.